# Kafka Connect Offsets. Get/Set?

Tags: apache-kafka

How do I get, set, or reset the offset of a Kafka Connect connector/task/sink?

I can use the `/usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups` tool which runs `kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand` to see the offsets for all my regular Kafka consumer groups. However, Kafka Connect tasks and groups do not show up with this tool.

Similarly, I can use the zookeeper-shell to connect to Zookeeper and I can see zookeeper entries for regular Kafka consumer groups, but not for Kafka Connect sinks.

Comment: As a (bad) workaround, you can delete the connector and register a new connector under a different name. Obviously, this only makes sense when you don't have to do this regularly.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670937/kafka-0-11-how-to-reset-offsets) is a nice explanation of how to modify the offsets for a group.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of 0.10.0.0, Connect doesn't provide an API for managing offsets. It's something we want to improve in the future, but not there yet. The `ConsumerGroupCommand` would be the right tool to manage offsets for Sink connectors. Note that source connector offsets are stored in a special offsets topic for Connect (they aren't like normal Kafka offsets since they are defined by the source system, see `offset.storage.topic` in the [worker configuration docs](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/userguide.html#distributed-worker-configuration)) and since sink Connectors uses the new consumer, they won't store their offsets in Zookeeper -- all modern clients use native Kafka-based offset storage. The `ConsumerGroupCommand` can work with these offsets, you just need to pass the `--new-consumer` option).

Comment: Any ETA or plans for this please? Can see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4107 also with no progress or details.

Answer (score 6):

You can't set offsets, but you can use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool to "scroll" the feed forward.

The consumer group of your connector has a name of `connect-*CONNECTOR NAME*`, but you can double check:

```
unset JMX_PORT; ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server *KAFKA HOSTS* --list
```

To view current offset:

```
unset JMX_PORT; ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server *KAFKA HOSTS* --group connect-*CONNECTOR NAME* --describe
```

To move the offset forward:

```
unset JMX_PORT; ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server *KAFKA HOSTS* --topic *TOPIC* --max-messages 10000 --consumer-property group.id=connect-*CONNECTOR NAME* > /dev/null
```

I suppose you can move the offset backward as well by deleting the consumer group first, using `--delete` flag.

Don't forget to pause and resume your connector via Kafka Connect REST API.

Comment: Even after pausing the connector, trying to delete the connect consumer group results in this error: "Group could not be deleted due to: NON_EMPTY_GROUP"

Comment: @emirhosseini Thanks for the warning but it's not the aim of this answer to show how to delete a consumer group in all possible circumstances.

Comment: This answer is for old versions of Kafka. As of 2.2.0, this does not work

Answer (score 2):

In my case(testing reading files into producer and consume in console, all in local only), I just saw this in producer output:

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

So I wanted to open it but it is binary, with some hardly recognizable characters.

I deleted it(rename it also works), and then I can write into the same file and get the file content from consumer again. **You have to restart the console producer to take effect because it attempts to read the offset file, if not there, create a new one, so that the offset is reset.**

If you want to reset it without deletion, you can use:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group <group-name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest --topic <topic_name>
```

You can check all group names by:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

and check details of each group:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group <group_name> --describe
```

In production environment, this offset is managed by zookeeper, so more steps (and caution) is needed. You can refer to this page:

https://metabroadcast.com/blog/resetting-kafka-offsets
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/81357/manually-resetting-offset-for-a-kafka-topic.html

Steps:

```
kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 -topic vital_signs --time -1 // -1 for largest, -2 for smallest

set /consumers/{yourConsumerGroup}/offsets/{yourFancyTopic}/{partitionId} {newOffset}
```

Comment: Kafka connect does not store offsets in zookeeper.  That is for old (0.8) kafka clients.  So this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Kafka 3.6, Kafka Connect supports first-class admin support (retrieve, alter, reset) for offsets:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-apache-kafka-3-6/#first-class%20offsets-support