# Kafka 0.11 how to reset offsets

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to reset consumer offset with latest CLI tools for Kafka.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group my-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics
```

As a result I see this output:

```
TOPIC                            PARTITION  NEW-OFFSET
FirstTopic                       0          0
SecondTopic                      0          0
```

But running again command:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group my-group --describe
```

results in output:

```
Consumer group 'my-group' has no active members.

TOPIC              PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
FirstTopic         0          1230            1230            0  
SecondTopic        0          1022            1022            0
```

I've tried other options like resetting to explicit offset or specifying the topic directly but result is same. The output suggests that operation succeed while checking offsets with describe command or debugging shows that offset has not be changed.

Anyone succeed with resetting consumer offset within non-zookeeper brokers.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

By default, `--reset-offsets` just prints the result of the operation. To actually perform the operation you need to add `--execute` to your command:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group
my-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics --execute
```

Comment: Any other options to reset to a specific offset, say 1200 for FirstTopic in the above question ? To be specific, I would like my consumer to reset to a specific point in time (whatever be the offset at that time)

Comment: I would also be interested in knowing how to accomplish these via the Kafka Java API.

Comment: Worth to also mention this gist: https://gist.github.com/marwei/cd40657c481f94ebe273ecc16601674b

Comment: kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group
my-group --reset-offsets --to-latest --all-topics --execute
Sh

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41645130/5368856

https://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/how-to-change-or-reset-consumer-offset-in-kafka/#:~:text=topic%20sales_topic%20%2D%2Dexecute-,%E2%80%93to%2Dlatest,-Reset%20offsets%20to

Answer (score 36):

Though the accepted answer perfectly answers OP question, there are more parameters available to reset offsets. So adding this answer to extend accepted answer.

To reset offset of all topics to earliest in the consumer group

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_broker_host:9091> --group
    <group_name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics --execute
```

To reset offset of specific topic to earliest in the consumer group

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_broker_host:9091> --group
    <group_name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest --topic <my-topic> --execute
```

To reset offset of specific topic to specific offset in the consumer group

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_broker_host:9091> --group
    <group_name> --reset-offsets --to-offset 1000 --topic <my-topic> --execute
```

**Other supported arguments:**

**--shift-by** [positive or negative integer] - Shifts offset forward or backward from given integer.

**--to-current** and **--to-latest** are same as **--to-offset** and **--to-earliest**.

**--to-datetime**  [Datetime format is **yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.xxx**]

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_broker_host:9091> --group
    <group_name> --reset-offsets --to-datetime 2017-08-04T00:00:00.000 [ --all-topics or --topic <topic-name> ] --execute
```

**--by-duration**  [Format is **PnDTnHnMnS**]

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_broker_host:9091> --group
    <group_name> --reset-offsets --by-duration PT0H10M0S [ --all-topics or --topic <topic-name> ] --execute
```

Reset to offset by duration from current timestamp.

**How to validate?**

Use below command to check current/end of offsets and to confirm reset made the cahnges.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_host:port> --group <group_id> --describe
```

**Sample output:**

```
Consumer group 'group1' has no active members.

TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
intro           0          0               99              99              -               -               -
```

**Possible Errors:**

> Error: Assignments can only be reset if the group '[group_name]' is inactive, but the current state is Stable.

'Stable' means, there is an active consumer running for this group. So first you have to stop the active consumer(s) and retry resetting offsets.

It is **not possible to reset offsets if there is an active consumer** for the consumer group.

Comment: , Is there any official documentation available for this ?

Answer (score 1):

For people who can't figure out what `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` is or are using [kt client](https://github.com/fgeller/kt)

```
kt group -reset oldest -topic <YOUR_TOPIC_NAME> -group <YOUR_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME> -partitions all -brokers <YOUR_BROKER>
```

You can also view its help manual for customization

```
$ kt -help
kt is a tool for Kafka.

Usage:

    kt command [arguments]

The commands are:

    consume        consume messages.
    produce        produce messages.
    topic          topic information.
    group          consumer group information and modification.
    admin          basic cluster administration.

Use "kt [command] -help" for for information about the command.

Authentication:

Authentication with Kafka can be configured via a JSON file.
You can set the file name via an "-auth" flag to each command or
set it via the environment variable KT_AUTH.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group my-group --reset-offsets --to-latest --all-topics --execute
Sh

./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41645130/5368856

[https://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/how-to-change-or-reset-consumer-offset-in-kafka/#:~:text=topic%20sales_topic%20%2D%2Dexecute-,%E2%80%93to%2Dlatest,-Reset%20offsets%20to](https://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/how-to-change-or-reset-consumer-offset-in-kafka/#:%7E:text=topic%20sales_topic%20%2D%2Dexecute-,%E2%80%93to%2Dlatest,-Reset%20offsets%20to)

**Describe the Kafka consumer group.**

```
cd /home/USER/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/bin
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group GROUPNAME
```

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.10/kafka-managing/topics/kafka-manage-cli-cgroups.html